# R shiny - error : must be a numeric

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)
library(frailtypack)
data("readmission", package = "frailtypack")
ui <- fluidPage(
 sidebarPanel(
  sliderInput("nb",
              h5("Number of time intervals  :"),
              min = 1,
              max = 20,
              value = 10)),
 mainPanel(
  verbatimTextOutput("mod"))
)
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$mod <- renderPrint({
        model <-frailtyPenal(Surv(time,event)~cluster(id)+ sex + dukes, data=readmission, 
                hazard = "Piecewise-per", nb.int = input$nb)   
        print(model)
      })
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hi, the code above sends me back as an error that nb.int must be numeric. While input$nb is a number.
I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty self-explanitory. `input$nb` is of class `integer` (`int`), but `frailtyPenal` expects a `numeric` (`double`). You can convert it with `as.numeric`.

Most R functions convert between types internally, so you probably won't see this very often but every now and then functions have very strict requirements for their input parameters.

```
library(shiny)
library(frailtypack)

data("readmission", package = "frailtypack")
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("nb",
                h5("Number of time intervals  :"),
                min = 1,
                max = 20,
                value = 10)),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("mod"))
)
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$mod <- renderPrint({
    message("start render")
    message(input$nb)
    message(class(input$nb))
    model <-frailtyPenal(Surv(time,event)~cluster(id)+ sex + dukes, data=readmission, 
                         hazard = "Piecewise-per", nb.int = as.numeric(input$nb))   
    print(model)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```